# Unload snd_usb_audio modules

Tags: audio, kernel-modules, usb-audio

I am trying to unload the `snd_usb_audio` kernel module in order to try some other module parameters (with `modprobe`).

This fails:

```
# rmmod snd_usb_audio
```

With the following error:

```
rmmod: ERROR: Module snd_usb_audio is in use
```

How can I quickly force the USB audio module to unload (without logging out/restarting)?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try  `rmmod -f snd_usb_audio` ?

Comment: Yes. It didn't work.